# How I can verify a googlebot

Tags: php, google

I'm going to block all bots except the big search engines.

One of my blocking methods will be to check for "language": `Accept-Language`

If it has no Accept-Language the bot's IP adress will be blocked untill 2037.

Googlebot do not have `Accept-Language`, I want to verify it with DNS lookup

```
<?php
    gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
?>
```

Is it ok to use `gethostbyaddr`, can someone pass my "`gethostbyaddr` protection"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really a question for Stack Overflow more than Server Fault (a SEO site would actually be best), but what you've got there is very unreliable. The googlebot could come from any numbers of IP addresses and thus reverse DNS lookups. There could be thousands of different options, and if one changes, then bam you've blocked a legitimate bot for almost 30 years.

In fact, I just found a [Stack Overflow question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916147/how-to-identify-web-crawlers-of-google-yahoo-msn-by-php) that answers your question. It was the first google hit for "[How to identify Google Bot](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=how+to+identify+google+bot&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a)".

> You identify search engines by user
>   agent and IP address. More info can be
>   found in How to identify search engine
>   spiders and webbots. It's also worth
>   noting this list. You shouldn't treat
>   user agents (or even remote hosts) as
>   necessarily definitive however. User
>   agents are really nothing more than
>   what the other end tells you it is and
>   it is of course free to tell you
>   anything. It's trivial to write code
>   to pretend to be Googlebot.

(Note: [Google actually suggest that you use RDNS to verify their bots](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=80553). This may be OK for their scenario, but it is certainly not a good idea for wider use. Plus it's very slow).